# EmEditor Sorting by multiple column groups

Tags: sorting, emeditor

In EmEditor I have a file with no delimiters per row. End of row is CR-LF. I want to bunch specific columns together (i.e. columns 1-10 &   440-445) and then sort on those two. I haven't figured out how dfo do that. I place separators for the specific columns bunched and and add a top Header line to designate each grouping. However, when I  go to the advanced Sort Screen there isn't a method to designate these column groups. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is, first convert your `Fixed Width Columns` file to a `CSV`. Then you can do multi-column sort. After that, you can convert your `CSV` back to `Fixed Width Columns`. To convert your file between Fixed Width Columns and CSV, you can open the `CSV Converter` by clicking the `CSV Convert` button on the `CSV/Sort` toolbar.